# Yii integrity constraint exception handling with user friendly message

Tags: exception, error-handling, referential-integrity, yii

I am using this model code to delete a record.

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
}
```

The table containing this record has one to many relationship with other table with on delete restrict constraint.

So when deleting a record which has related records in child table it throws exception like

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bzuexamsystem`.`campus`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Campus_City` FOREIGN KEY (`CityID`) REFERENCES `city` (`CityID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE). The SQL statement executed was: DELETE FROM `city` WHERE `city`.`CityID`=1
```

Is there someway to show user friendly error message. Thanks

Comment: you mean like try/catch?

Comment: if ($this->loadModel($id)->delete()){...} else {...} should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, $this->loadModel() returns a CActiveRecord object...

First at all you need to make sure the record you want to delete is really loaded. Second, use @ at the start of the statement do disallow errors. Then if the CActiveRecord->delete() returns false, it means, that the record wasn't deleted:

```
public function actionDelete($id) {
    $record = $this->loadModel($id);
    if ($record !== null) {
        if (@$record->delete()) {
            // code when successfully deleted
        } else {
            // code when delete fails
        }
    } else {
        // optional code to handle "record isn't found" case
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to catch exception. Something like

```
try{
    $this->loadModel($id)->delete();
    if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }catch (CDbException $e){
        if($e->getCode()===23000){
            //You can have nother error handling
            header("HTTP/1.0 400 Relation Restriction");
        }else{
            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

If you also use CGrigView in your view file, you should pass "ajaxUpdateError" function to it. 
Example:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',
  array(
    'id' => 'model-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'ajaxUpdateError' => <<<JS
      function(xhr, ts, et, err){
        if(xhr.statusText==="Relation Restriction"){
          $("#errorDiv").text("That model is used by something!");
        }
        else{
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    JS
    ,
    'columns' => 
        array(
            'model_id',
            'name'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete rows that have restrict on the foreign key, change that to `set to null`, or `no action` depending on your requirements

so your key would be `set to null` on delete
and `cascade` on `update`